# Beginner Python Functions & Loops

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, spyder

I have been stuck at this question for the past day and would appreciate any help!

2. In a firm, employees are paid based on their years of work experience.

Work Experience(years) Salary
0-3                  $25000
4-8                  $50000
9-13                $75000
14-20                $100000
more than 20 years              $150000

There are 4 employees from the same family with experience of 8 years, 25 years, 15
years and 45 years. Using the function created in a), and a loop, calculate and print
the total income of this family. Then, let the user know if the family’s total income is
more than $150,000. You do not need to take any inputs from the user for this
question.

I have already come up with this function so far,

```
def salary(experience):
if experience <=3.9:
    return "$25000"
elif experience <=8.9:
    return "$50000"
elif experience <=13.9:
    return "$75000"
elif experience <=20:
    return "$100000"
else:
   return "$150000"
```

and I now need to embed it in a loop but can't for the life of me!
Any advice would be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop at all? What belongs inside the loop? What kind of loop should it be? Why should there be a loop? What exactly is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't properly sum strings. Therefore you need to convert them into numbers. Then you iterate over every employee experience and run the function to get a salary for each employee. You sum this number and check if it is greater than `150000`

Here it is

```
def get_salary_from_experience(experience):
    if experience <= 3.9:
        return 25000
    elif experience <= 8.9:
        return 50000
    elif experience <= 13.9:
        return 75000
    elif experience <= 20:
        return 100000
    else:
        return 150000


employee_experience_list = [8, 25, 15, 45]

salary_sum = 0

for employee_exp in employee_experience_list:
    salary_sum += get_salary_from_experience(employee_exp)

print("Total salary {}".format(salary_sum))


if salary_sum > 150_000:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("Not")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as you expect. Please try all other solutions with 9 years it works but you should not set limits like 8.9 it returns 75000 for 8.95 year experience. However it should have returned $50,000

```
family_experience_list = [5,9,11,14]

def salary(experience):
    if experience <4:
        return 25000
    elif experience <9:
        return 50000
    elif experience <14:
        return 75000
    elif experience <=20:
        return 100000
    else:
       return 150000

total_salary = 0
for exp in family_experience_list:
    cr_salary = salary(exp)
    total_salary += cr_salary
    print("{}$ salary for {} experience".format(cr_salary, exp))

if total_salary > 150000:
    print("\nThe family income exceeds 150,000.")
else:
    print("\nThe family income is less than or equal to 150,000.")
```